# Unity 5.4 UNetWeaver error: ResolveMethod failed

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity3d-unet

I am having this error even in empty projects.

i am using Unity 5.4.03

```
UNetWeaver error: ResolveMethod failed NetworkBehaviour::SendTargetRPCInternal UnityEngine.Networking.NetworkBehaviour
UnityEngine.Debug:LogError(Object)
Unity.UNetWeaver.Log:Error(String) (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/Extensions/Networking/Weaver/Program.cs:20)
Unity.UNetWeaver.Weaver:ResolveMethod(TypeReference, String) (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/Extensions/Networking/Weaver/UNetWeaver.cs:1088)
Unity.UNetWeaver.Weaver:SetupTargetTypes() (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/Extensions/Networking/Weaver/UNetWeaver.cs:1352)
Unity.UNetWeaver.Weaver:Weave(String, IEnumerable`1, IAssemblyResolver, String, String, String) (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/Extensions/Networking/Weaver/UNetWeaver.cs:1652)
Unity.UNetWeaver.Weaver:WeaveAssemblies(IEnumerable`1, IEnumerable`1, IAssemblyResolver, String, String, String) (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/Extensions/Networking/Weaver/UNetWeaver.cs:1763)
Unity.UNetWeaver.Program:Process(String, String, String, String[], String[], IAssemblyResolver, Action`1, Action`1) (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/Extensions/Networking/Weaver/Program.cs:34)
UnityEditor.Scripting.Serialization.Weaver:WeaveUnetFromEditor(String, String, String, String, Boolean)
```

Comment: Same here, please ping me if you find a solution.

Comment: i just install new version of Unity, which is working fine now, but can't actually find solution for that error, there is no help yet from unity as well.

Answer (score 0):

the way it worked for me was removing the old installation of Unity that I still had on the mac. Also, I removed Unity 5.4.1 and installed 5.4.1 again now on a complete Unity free system.
That made the error disappear.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem. I am in OSX 10.9.5. However, I would like to note that this wouldn't happen in an an empty project until I added a script to it.   Also, this error would prevent me from being able to build or play the scene.

I think I did what @Thor_Bux did.  I only had one copy of Unity installed. This copy was 5.4.1.  I moved the Unity folder, in the Applications folder, to the trash.  I then reinstalled using 5.4.2.  I continued to receive the errors.

I rebooted to Linux, and installed Unity 5.4.1(the latest version).  I received no errors.  I rebooted back to OSX.  I then decided to empty the trash can.  After starting Unity 5.4.2, everything seems to be working and that error seems to be gone.

I don't know if it had something to do with rebooting, or emptying my trash can, or something else entirely.

Another thing I would like to add, before I started receiving, the unetweaver errors, the Unity Download Assistant wouldn't work for me.  So, I installed Unity 5.4.1 using a pkg folder(I left the old Unity install in place and installed over it.  I think it was 5.3.x).  This is when the unetweaver error started to occur.  The Unity Download Assistant didn't start working for me until after I removed the Unity Applications Folder and then tried to reinstall, in the process of trying to fix the unetweaver error.  I don't know if this was a coincidence.

Before I got this working,  I created two bug reports for this issue.  Unity told me my issue was a duplicate and directed me toward this issue https://issuetracker.unity3d.com/issues/mono-runtime-upgrade-unetweaver-5-dot-5-0b4-with-monoupdate-failes-to-compile-a-project

tl;dr.  If in OSX, try deleting your Unity folder in the "Applications folder" and then reinstalling.  If that doesn't work, empty your trash can.  If that doesn't work try rebooting.

If I had to venture a guess, I would guess the unetweaver errors had something to do with installing a newer version of Unity over an older version, but that's just a guess.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a Command method (used to send a message from a client to the server) which required an unusable parameter. In my case it was a class that I had written.  UNET can only pass certain objects into Command methods, which does not include your own classes!

Check what parameters you're using for all of your Commands and ClientRPC methods.